# Read table header value from the chosen (clicked) cell

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how can I get a certain heading value in a table, just by finding out which cell was clicked.

I know I can get the cell value like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytbl'),
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    cells[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
```

but how could I get it to read the heading value.

e.g if b2 is clicked I want to get the x2 value and if a3 is clicked I want x3 value, etc...

```
x1 x2 x3
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry but I want to make sure, are x1,x2,x3 are th or simple td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `cellIndex`

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytbl'),
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
  cells[i].onclick = function () {
    var th= table.getElementsByTagName('th')[this.cellIndex];
    console.log(th.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A9p3E/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one handler for a table like this. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/tyK24/).

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var position = e.target.cellIndex, //clicked td index if any

        header = position !== undefined && table.rows[0].cells[position].innerHTML; 
       //first row at pos.    

    if(!header) return;

    console.log(header);        
});
```